# load dynamic website pages with out page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, .htaccess

I have created a shell like html page which loads other pages into div on link clicks.The issue i am having is to rewrite the url with out a page re-load.
Also checking for hash events to add and rewrite them.

Firstly the links;

```
<a href = "myexample" onclick="menuPage(this);return false;" >
   //result www.mywebsite.com/myexample
```

```js
function loadPage(){
  var tempURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $("a[data-role="+tempURL+"]").parent().addClass('active');
  if(!tempURL){
    $('#pages').animate({opacity: '0.0'},function(){
      $("a[data-role='Home']").parent().addClass('active');
      $.get('Home/index.html', function(response){
        $('#pages').html(response);
        scrollOnTop();
        $('#pages').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
      })    
    });
  }else{

    $('#pages').animate({opacity: '0.0'},function(){   
      jQuery.post(tempURL, function(response){

        $('#pages').html(response);
        ga('send',{    // google 
          'hitType': 'pageview',
          'title': 'mywebsite',
          'location':'http://www.mywebsite.com/'+ tempURL,
          'page': '/'+ tempURL
        });    

        document.title = $(response).filter('title').text();
        scrollOnTop();
        $('#pages').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
        tempURL = "";
      })
    });
  }
}
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
  loadPage();     
});
function menuPage(obj){

  menu =  "#" + obj.getAttribute("href");
  window.location = menu;
  return false; 
}

function scrollOnTop(){
  jQuery("html, body").scrollTop(0);    
}    
//The above works 100% expected:**
```

So lets say i click link or enter the url www.myexample.com/#item1  this will take me to that page all good **but** lets say i click or type in www.myexample.com/item1 with out hash this will take to the page but all broken as there is a folder named "item1" with an index file in it...

Essentially i would like to add hash into the url:
   Once i add to the .htaccess file anything along the lines of : RewriteRule

```
 ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ # [NC,NE,R=301]
```

or variations.

This just messes up.

Comment: This will point you in the right direction: https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: I had came across similiar things, but there not a solid solution

Comment: is history.pushState() what you're looking for? It can change the actual URL and also the hash part if you want without a page reload. Ie 9 is not supported though and a hash should be used for ie 9

Comment: Sounds like this would be easier using something like angular with routing

Comment: Essentially i don't need angular for something thats 98% working... And also i have never used angular.js  ,  with many other things in the way. I Appreciate the input guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand what your code is doing. A jsfiddle or equivalent might help.

It looks like loadPage is only executed when the url hash changes? And an anchor with href of www.myexample.com/item1 doesn't result in a hash change.

My guess is you want to bind a click event to your anchors, so you can intercept the click and run your own custom code (load page snippet without refresh), instead of the browser default behaviour of requesting the url (www.myexample.com/item1) from the server.

Something like:

```
$('a').click(function() {

    /* Your code here. E.g... */

    $('#pages').animate({opacity: '0.0'},function(){
        $("a[data-role='Home']").parent().addClass('active');
        $.get('Home/index.html', function(response){
            $('#pages').html(response);
            scrollOnTop();
            $('#pages').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
        })  
    });

    // Returning false prevents browser default behaviour
    // Some people don't like it - see http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/
    return false;

});
```

Comment: The hash changes also on link click, The issue is more referring to .htaccessfile now rewritting urls with a hash... for example : www.myweb.com/page1   need it to rewrite www.myweb.com/#page1?any-String-Here-so-i-can-check-this-with-js-in-the-hash-change-function/